# How can I make the wiggler parts show up on my map?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

How can I make the wiggler parts show up on my map? The one in the loop loop river place had a wiggler icon above the level until I found it, but none of the other levels have that. This is stopping me from finding any other parts.

[image: Image showing the map of world 3. Mario is on 3-5 Loop Loop River, which is marked blue, as are the adjacent courses north and south. There are 2 unlocked courses to the west. Both are marked yellow.]

Answer (score 1):

They show on the map automatically, after Mario becomes aware of their location (sort of). If I remember correctly, if you get a wiggler part, but it then runs of to another level, you can see where it ran off to using that marker.

This would help if you looked away from the screen in the short cutscene of the part running of, or forgot where it went.

You can’t “make them appear”. You have to find the parts.